# Android aparece mensagem no log sobre configuração de segurança

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

Tenho uma aplicação que faz consulta de dados em um WebService usando JSON. Quando vou executar minha aplicação recebo a seguinte mensagem nos logs:

```
D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
```

Isso é um erro, pode ser resolvido ou não afeta meu programa?

Answer (score 1):

Essa mensagem não é um erro. Quer dizer que você não configurou uma opção de segurança específica para utilizar no seu aplicativo, portanto ele irá utilizar as configurações padrão do Android.

Se você  quiser saber mais sobre elas, pode usar  as informações do link: https://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-config?hl=pt-br